# Excel data sometimes can't refresh using Python (win32com.client)

Tags: python, powerquery

OS: Windows 10
Office: Microsoft 365
Python: 3.11

We need to use Power Query to update a large number of Excel reports every day, so we have adopted win32com as the most efficient library.

However, recently we have frequently encountered the above prompt message during updates and false, which requires us to manually check and update every day.

```
import os
import shutil
import time
import win32com.client as win32
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import os.path
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
from time import localtime, strftime

today = date.today()
date=datetime.datetime.now()
date=str(date.year)+"-"+str(date.month)+"-"+str(date.day)+" "+str(date.hour)+"00"
os.system("taskkill /f /im  EXCEL.exe")

target=r"C:\xxxxxxx.xlsx"

xl = win32.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(target) 
xl.Visible = True
wb.RefreshAll()
xl.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
wb.Close(True)
xl.Quit()
os.system("taskkill /f /im  EXCEL.exe")
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10728\3785860152.py in <module>
     20 wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(target)
     21 xl.Visible = True
---> 22 wb.RefreshAll()
     23 xl.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
     24 wb.Close(True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in RefreshAll(self)

com_error: (-2147023170, 'The remote procedure call failed.', None, None)
```

When my .py updates more than one excel file ,the situation is more likely to occur.
When I restart my computer or wait some time, the script may works fine.

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated.